# Form with multiple submit buttons doesn't submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have multiple buttons in one form that submit. On submit, it's going to go to a different page and I'm also going to have it pass in some variables

```
echo "
                                                <form method=\"POST\" action=\"sightWordsTest.php\">
                                                    <tr style=\"text-align: center;\">
                                                        <td>".$firstname."</td>
                                                        <td>".$middlename."</td>
                                                        <td>".$lastname."</td>
                                                        <td><button type=\"submit\" name=\"button_1\" class=\"btn btn-default\">".$assess1."/25</button></td>
                                                        <td><button type=\"submit\" name=\"button_2\" class=\"btn btn-default\">".$assess2."/50</button></td>
                                                        <td><button type=\"submit\" name=\"button_3\" class=\"btn btn-default\">".$assess3."/100</button></td>
                                                        <td><button type=\"submit\" name=\"button_4\" class=\"btn btn-default\">".$assess4."/200</button></td>
                                                        <td><input type=\"button\" class=\"open-Modal btn btn-info\" value=\"Start Test\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#testModal\" data-studentid=\"$studentID\" data-firstname=\"$firstname\" data-middlename=\"$middlename\" data-lastname=\"$lastname\"/></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </form>";
                                            }
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' at end of your code...

Comment: What you've given here is basically like going to a mechanic and saying, "Here's the keys; something is wrong; I'll be back in an hour." What are you expecting/wanting to happen? What *variables* are you *also going to have it pass*? What is currently happening when you click *any* of the submit buttons ("doesn't submit" is too ambiguous)? Is the form posting per its action (taking you to sightWordsTest.php)? Does *nothing* happen, as in when you click any of the submit buttons the page simply stays put? Etc. Any/all relevant information helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify `value` attribute for your submit buttons like

```
<td><button type=\"submit\" name=\"button_1\" value=\"1\" class=\"btn btn-default\">".$assess1."/25</button></td>
<td><button type=\"submit\" name=\"button_2\" value=\"2\" class=\"btn btn-default\">".$assess2."/50</button></td>
<td><button type=\"submit\" name=\"button_3\" value=\"3\" class=\"btn btn-default\">".$assess3."/100</button></td>
<td><button type=\"submit\" name=\"button_4\" value=\"4\" class=\"btn btn-default\">".$assess4."/200</button></td>
```

Comment: and then what? I don't think he'll know what to do on the next page, for example `if (isset($_POST['button_1'])) {` or `if ($_POST['button_1'] == '1') {`. However he's been so vague about what he wants to achieve.

Comment: I don't know if button names were specified differently on purpose, it might be used to trigger different events after form is submitted